# Can I compare two COUNT statements in the HAVING clause in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

I'm trying to solve part (b) of this question, and I'm not sure if the query I came up with is right:

```
SELECT C.ISBN
FROM COPY C, LOAN L
WHERE C.ISBN = L.ISBN
GROUP BY C.ISBN
HAVING COUNT(C.ISBN) > COUNT(L.ISBN);
```

Comment: Sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but because you are effectively doing an INNER JOIN between `Copy` and `Loan`, then `COUNT(C.ISBN)` will always be the same as `COUNT(L.ISBN)`.

One way to fix this is to make it a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT C.ISBN
FROM COPY C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LOAN L ON C.ISBN = L.ISBN
GROUP BY C.ISBN
HAVING COUNT(C.ISBN) > COUNT(L.ISBN);
```

This should work as COUNT(column_name) will not include NULLs in the count.

While the above will work, however, it will actually produce a fairly large internal table during the calculation as (the JOIN condition is only on ISBN, meaning it will multiply out results) e.g., if there are 20 rows in Copy for a given ISBN, and 15 rows in Loans, COUNT(C.ISBN) will be 300 and COUNT(L.ISBN) will be 225 if my maths is correct.

There are ways to make it more efficient.

Alternate method 1: Include CopyNumber in the join e.g.,

```
SELECT C.ISBN
FROM COPY C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LOAN L ON C.ISBN = L.ISBN AND C.CopyNumber = L.Copy
GROUP BY C.ISBN
HAVING COUNT(C.ISBN) > COUNT(L.ISBN);
```

Alternate method 2: Find specific CopyNumbers which aren't loaned out

You could also do this with a similar query but joined on ISBN and CopyNumber to find any specific copy numbers are not loaned out e.g.,

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.ISBN
FROM COPY C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LOAN L ON C.ISBN = L.ISBN AND C.CopyNumber = L.Copy
WHERE L.ISBN IS NULL
```

Alternate method 3: Do the counts first, then join

```
SELECT C.ISBN
FROM (SELECT ISBN, COUNT(*) AS NumCopies FROM COPY GROUP BY ISBN) C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT ISBN, COUNT(*) AS NumLoans FROM LOAN GROUP BY ISBN) L 
       ON C.ISBN = L.ISBN AND C.CopyNumber = L.Copy
WHERE (C.ISBN > L.ISBN) OR (L.ISBN IS NULL);
```

These will all achieve the results you're trying to achieve with the initial query. But there is another question - is this the correct approach? What happens when a person returns a book? For a given book that is frequently lent out, would the data look like, say,

- 3 copies in the Copy table,
- but 50 rows in the Loans table

the next question is how would this approach deal with this properly?

Comment: Note - the above (except the part at the end about returns) are ways to tweak your original SQL to do what I think you were trying to do. However, in re-reading the question, it also seems possible they are actually just asking "which books have a record in the Copy table?" which seems trivial, but it is ambiguous what "available" means in the question.